# I need a way to edit/delete files from Windows on a Samba share

Tags: networking, 20.04, permissions, samba

I copied a lot from one NTSF HDD to an NTSF SSD using rsync and since then everything is owned by root. Everything else is put there by bittorrent-nox. I want a way to allow my windows networked machines to modify these files.

I have done `sudo chmod -R 0777 ./` on the whole mounted drive but still get "need permission from root" when I try to modify or delete a file.

I then did `sudo chown -R :users ./` but it still doesn't let me modify anything owned by root.

Yes I was in `/media/ssd` for both commands, that's the mount point for the external via fstab.

Here is a sample `ls -l`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6920859442 Oct  6  2022  Three.Thousand.Years.Of.Longing.2022.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.H.264-SMURF.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      88560 Jun 17 23:23  Three.Thousand.Years.Of.Longing.Chinese-WWW.MY-SUBS.CO.srt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      88560 Jun 17 23:23 'Unconfirmed 450771.crdownload'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      88560 Jun 17 23:22 'Unconfirmed 898564.crdownload'
```

Shouldn't the fact they are 0777 mean I should be able to modify them?

This is the fstab mount for the drive:

```
UUID=2C9CD48B9CD450C6   /media/ssd      auto    user,nofail,umask=000,utf8      0       0
```

Samba is setup via a 3rd party admin and looks like the below image, maybe Samba is the problem and I should move back to using the samba.config instead?

[image: Samba File Share Options]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing fstab entry and adding uid and gid so it looks like the following:

```
UUID=2C9CD48B9CD450C6   /media/ssd      auto    users,uid=1000,gid=1000,nofail,umask=000,utf8   0       0
```